# Sparql Construct statement containing count(?var)

Tags: sparql

data.ttl:

```
@base <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix : <http://example.org/#> .

:Bob a :Student;
     :tookTest :Test0,:Test1,:Test2, :Test3, :Test4, :Test5, :Test6, :Test7, :Test8, :Test9.

:Test0  :grade "A" .
:Test1  :grade "A" .
:Test2  :grade "A" .
:Test3  :grade "A" .
:Test4  :grade "A" .
:Test5  :grade "A" .
:Test6  :grade "A" .
:Test7  :grade "B" .
:Test8  :grade "C" .
:Test9  :grade "D" .
```

sparql query:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/#>
SELECT  ?student ?grade (count(?grade) as ?count)
    WHERE {
           ?student :tookTest ?test .
           ?test :grade ?grade .
          }
    GROUP BY ?student ?grade
    order by ?grade
```

I get result like follows:

```
student,  grade,  count
http://example.org/#Bob,A,7
http://example.org/#Bob,B,1
http://example.org/#Bob,C,1
http://example.org/#Bob,D,1
```

Now how can I get the same result with Construct?
I used the following query statement, but I didn't get any expected results:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/#>
CONSTRUCT {?student ?grade ?count .}
WHERE {
      SELECT  ?student ?grade (count(?grade) as ?count)
      WHERE {
              ?student :tookTest ?test .
              ?test :grade ?grade .
           }
       GROUP BY ?student ?grade
}
```

How do I write this Sparql CONSTRUCT statement correctly?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: counting the grades doesn't make sense if you use the `grade` already as a group. It's obviously always `1` then. You should count the tests then: `SELECT  ?student ?grade (count(?test) as ?count)`

Comment: Whether the count (?grade) or count (?test) the SELECT statements can return results correctly,  but the  CONSTRUCT does not return any results.

Comment: right, I'm dumb as I didn't read the `CONSTRUCT` template part carefully

Answer (score 0):

I got it done.
replace all "A" with :A , so do with "B", "C", "D".
then everything is OK.

Comment: I didn't read the `CONSTRUCT` template carefully - the reason is that predicates in RDF can't be literals and your grades are literals. Clearly, having properties `:A`, `:B`, ... could be one way, but honestly the semantic meaning is rather low with this way. For a proper modeling I'd more go with some pattern like `:gradeAchieved [ :count 7; :grade "A" ] .` - but it's a matter of taste and depends on how you want to use the data in future

Comment: Thanks a lot, UninformedUser,  The second way you said is also very meaningful, in fact, I think this way is more widely used.